# Java based selenium webdriver - click on element in dynamically changing table content by row text ( click input by text in same row )

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Im stucked in java based selenium usage, i like to click on input box (within table )by  another cell text value

Here is my HTML code:

```
<DIV class=>
<P class=></P>
<UL></UL>
<FORM id="" onsubmit="" method=post name="" action="">
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE class="" width="70%">
<TBODY>
<TR class="">
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class="">
<TD><INPUT class="" onclick="" CHECKED type=checkbox><INPUT id= value=true type=hidden name=""> </TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id="" class= onclick='' value="" type=button name=></TD></TR></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=""></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE class=foo width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR class=foo-header>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class="foo-odd">
<TD><INPUT onclick="" value="0" type="radio" name=""> </TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class="foo-even">
<TD rowSpan="3"><INPUT onclick="" value="1" CHECKED type="radio" name=""> </TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD rowSpan="3"><INPUT id="" class="" value="" type="" name=""></TD></TR>
<TR class="foo-even">
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class="foo">
<TD>CCC</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT class="" onclick="" type=checkbox><INPUT id="" value="false" type="hidden" name=""> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=""></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE class="foo" width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR class="foo-header">
<TD></TD>
<TD><BR><INPUT id="" class="" onclick="" value="" type="button" name=""></TD>
<TD colSpan="3"></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class="foo-odd">
<TD><INPUT value="0" type="radio" name=""> </TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD colSpan="2"></TD>
<TD><SELECT class="" name=""> <OPTION value="0"></OPTION> <OPTION selected value="1"></OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>
<TR class="foo-even">
<TD rowSpan="2"><INPUT value="1" type="radio" name=""> </TD>
<TD rowSpan="2"></TD>
<TD rowSpan="2"></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD rowSpan="2"><SELECT class="" name=""> <OPTION value="0"></OPTION> <OPTION selected value="1"></OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>
<TR class="foo">
<TD>CCC</TD>
<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY>
</DIV>
```

I like to click on the second CCC text row related input,(not by only clicking name or xpath) im tried with followings:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[contains(text(),'CCC')]/preceding-sibling::td")).click();
```

Code above working in a *very similar html only contains CCC one time (tested with another HTML code )

```
WebElement services = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='installationAddressForm']/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1][contains(text(),'CCC')]"));
         String contents = services.getText();
         System.out.println(contents);
```

Code above able to find text but when combined with the top code(/preceding-sibling::td) it cannot find the input

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The expression `td[1][contains(text(),'CCC')]` selects the first `td` and tests whether its text contains `CCC`.

Replace it with `td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1]`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but i like to click on text related input field whitin the table/row, not just the text [code].//td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1]/preceding-sibling::td [/code] :unable to find element with xpath ==

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the rest. How are you combining the two?

Comment: .//td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1] part1: you suggested working fine, but i think the problem with the second part of the code /preceding-sibling::td   -- full merged code: [code].//td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1]/preceding-sibling::td [/code]

Comment: Indeed: the `td` you select does not have a preceding sibling! What you're looking for is the previous `td` in the tree, but that `td` does not have the same parent.

Comment: thank you for help, now im closer to the final solution, but the above code is populated by backend information - the table size is changing case by case, currently im working with the following: [code]".//td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1][last()]/following::tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input [/code], the above case its working well but when CCC in another position, the code click to always same non-relevant input

Comment: Poor HTML design you can't fix - what else is new :)  I'm not sure XPath can actually express the query you seem to need, so my solution would be to do it in whatever language you're using for Selenium: retrieve the array of `td`s with `findElements`, find the first one whose text matches `CCC` and take the previous one.

Comment: Im trying with something like this: int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'CCC')][1]")).size(); then put rowCount to xpath value - 
Im still closer to the solution, but its inaccurately clicking on input

Comment: What I was thinking of is something like `WebElement[] tds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td")); for (int i = tds.size(); i > 0; --i) { if (By.xpath(".[contains(text()),'CCC')]) { return tds[i-1]; } }` (untested!)

Comment: List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td"));
        for (int i = tds.size(); i > 0; --i) 
        { if (By.xpath(".[contains(text()),'CCC')]") != null)
          { 
          //nomatterwhatido "CCC"or"Nonexist Element" //
          }
        } its give back always same result,